# Why can't AzureRmAks find SSH key when deploying new Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: azure, powershell, kubernetes, ssh, azure-aks

Last night I used PowerShell to deploy a Kubernetes cluster on AKS with something like this:

```
New-AzureRmAks -ResourceGroupName "my-rg" -Name "my-aks-cluster" -KubernetesVersion "1.16.13" -NodeCount 2 -NodeVmSize "Standard_DS2_V2" -Verbose
```

This worked fine. Today, however, I tried this same thing in a different subscription, but keep getting the following error:

```
VERBOSE: Cluster does not exist.
VERBOSE: Cluster is new.
VERBOSE: Performing the operation "Creating a managed Kubernetes cluster." on target "my-aks-cluster in my-rg".
VERBOSE: Preparing for deployment of your managed Kubernetes cluster.
VERBOSE: Using location eastus from the resource group my-rg.
VERBOSE: Using DNS name prefix my-aks-cluster-my-rg-dcdf2a.
VERBOSE: Fetching SSH public key from file C:\Users\myuser\.ssh\id_rsa.pub
New-AzureRmAks : The given key was not present in the dictionary.
At line:1 char:1
+ New-AzureRmAks -ResourceGroupName "my-reg" -Name "my-aks-cluster" -Kube ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [New-AzureRmAks], KeyNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Aks.NewAzureRmAks
```

I'm confused because:

1. This same command worked earlier
2. I have same admin rights to new subscription as to the one previously used
3. The path to the key is valid
4. The key, id_rsa.pub, is at the path listed

Anyone have an idea what is going on here? Any tips are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce this issue with the same user account when only changing to a new subscription in another directory.

To fix it, you can delete all files but leave `TokenCache.dat` file in the `.Azure` folder of the path

```
C:\Users\myuser\.Azure
```

[image]

Then re-connect the subscription.

[image]

### Edit

In this case, deleting the file `acsServicePrincipal` under the local `.azure`  directory is to fix this issue.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this! This did not work for me unfortunately. I also tried deleting the old keys and regenerating new ones, which also didn't work.

Comment: Could you try to delete the file `acsServicePrincipal` under the `.azure` directory? For me. It always works when that file is deleted, then run the New-AzureRmAks. It worked.